# How to log ServiceStack.Messaging.Message to a database with OrmLite?

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Given the following code:

```
public class AppHost : BasicAppHost
{
    public AppHost()
        : base(typeof(LeadService).Assembly){}

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        SetConfig(new HostConfig
        {
            DebugMode = ConfigUtils.GetAppSetting<bool>("DebugMode:Enabled", false)
        });

        //DataAccess
        //Set ORMLite to work with columns like ColumnLikeThis
        PostgreSqlDialect.Provider.NamingStrategy = new OrmLiteNamingStrategyBase();
        //Set ORMLite to use ServiceStack.Text for JSON serialization 
        PostgreSqlDialect.Provider.StringSerializer = new JsonStringSerializer();
        var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(ConfigUtils.GetConnectionString("Lead:Default"), PostgreSQLDialectProvider.Instance);
        container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(dbFactory);

        //RabbitMQ
        container.Register<IMessageService>(c => new RabbitMqServer() 
        {
            AutoReconnect = true,
            DisablePriorityQueues = true,

        });
        var mqServer = container.Resolve<IMessageService>();

        //Handlers
        container.Register<IMessageHandlers>(c => new MessageHandlers(c.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>()));
        var handlers = container.Resolve<IMessageHandlers>();

        mqServer.RegisterHandler<LeadInformation>(handlers.OnProcessLeadInformation, handlers.OnExceptionLeadInformation);

        mqServer.Start();       
    }
}


public class MessageHandlers : IMessageHandlers
{
    private readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MessageHandlers));

    private readonly IDbConnectionFactory _connectionFactory; 

    public MessageHandlers(IDbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
    {
        _connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
    }

    public object OnProcessLeadInformation(IMessage<LeadInformation> request)
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        try
        {
            // Log to the database
            using (var db = _connectionFactory.OpenDbConnection())
            {
                db.CreateTableIfNotExists<Message>();
                var msg = request as Message<LeadInformation>; // Anyway not to have to cast it?
                db.Save(msg); // Does not work
            }
            // Run rules against lead

            // Log response to database

            // return response
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _log.Error(request, exception);
        }
        return new LeadInformationResponse
        {
            TimeTakenMs = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds,
            Result = "Processed lead {0}".Fmt(request.GetBody().LeadApplication.LastName)
        };
    }

    public void OnExceptionLeadInformation(IMessage<LeadInformation> request, Exception exception)
    {
        _log.Error(request, exception);
    }

}
```

Is it possible to persist the whole message? The table gets created, and I was able to save one message, and that's it no more saves with different messages.

**Update**

Turns out I'm getting an exception during the save operation

Npgsql.NpgsqlException was caught
  _HResult=-2147467259
  _message=ERROR: 42P01: relation "Message`1" does not exist
  HResult=-2147467259
  IsTransient=false
  Message=ERROR: 42P01: relation "Message`1" does not exist
  Source=Npgsql
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  BaseMessage=relation "Message`1" does not exist
  Code=42P01
  ColumnName=""
  ConstraintName=""
  DataTypeName=""
  Detail=""
  ErrorSql=SELECT "Id", "CreatedDate", "Priority", "RetryAttempts", "ReplyId", "ReplyTo", "Options", "Error", "Tag", "Body" FROM "Message`1" WHERE "Id" = (('ab297bca-5aea-4886-b09b-5a606b0764d5')::uuid)
  File=src\backend\parser\parse_relation.c
  Hint=""
  Line=986
  Position=119
  Routine=parserOpenTable
  SchemaName=""
  Severity=ERROR
  TableName=""
  Where=""
  StackTrace:
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlState.d__0.MoveNext()
       at Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.GetNextResponseObject(Boolean cleanup)
       at Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.GetNextRowDescription()
       at Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.NextResultInternal()
       at Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader..ctor(IEnumerable`1 dataEnumeration, CommandBehavior behavior, NpgsqlCommand command, NotificationThreadBlock threadBlock, Boolean preparedStatement, NpgsqlRowDescription rowDescription)
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.GetReader(CommandBehavior cb)
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cb)
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
       at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteReadExtensions.ExecReader(IDbCommand dbCmd, String sql)
       at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteResultsFilterExtensions.ConvertTo[T](IDbCommand dbCmd, String sql)
       at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteReadExtensions.SingleById[T](IDbCommand dbCmd, Object value)
       at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteWriteExtensions.Save[T](IDbCommand dbCmd, T obj)
       at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteWriteConnectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass5a`1.b__58(IDbCommand dbCmd)
       at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteExecFilter.Exec[T](IDbConnection dbConn, Func`2 filter)
       at ServiceStack.OrmLite.ReadConnectionExtensions.Exec[T](IDbConnection dbConn, Func`2 filter)
       at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteWriteConnectionExtensions.Save[T](IDbConnection dbConn, T obj, Boolean references)
       at LO.Leads.Processor.ServiceInterface.MessageHandlers.OnProcessLeadInformation(IMessage`1 request) in e:\Lead\src\LO.Leads.Processor\LO.Leads.Processor.ServiceInterface\MessageHandlers.cs:line 41

**Update 2**

Turns out my cast was wrong, this now works

```
using (var db = _connectionFactory.OpenDbConnection())
{
    db.CreateTableIfNotExists<Message>();
    db.Save(request as Message);
}
```

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast the IMessage back to a Message DTO in order for it to work. e.g.

```
using (var db = _connectionFactory.OpenDbConnection())
{
    db.CreateTableIfNotExists<Message>();
    db.Save(request as Message);
}
```